# Mapping Business Objects with Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping

I am new in iOS. Can anyone tell about how I can map my BO with Core Data so that I may reuse mapping in my project. Here is my code

```
- (void) saveData
{       
    CoredataAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *newContact;

    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newContact setValue:firstName.text forKey:@"firstName"];
    [newContact setValue:lastName.text forKey:@"lastName"];
    [newContact setValue:driverLicenceno.text forKey:@"driverLicenceNumber"];
    [newContact setValue:state.text forKey:@"state"];
    [newContact setValue:phoneNO.text forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
    [newContact setValue:injuryStatus.text forKey:@"injuryStatus"];
    [newContact setValue:emailAddress.text forKey:@"emailAddress"];

    NSLog(@"fName%@",firstName.text);
    firstName.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"fName%@",firstName.text);
    lastName.text = @"";
    driverLicenceno.text = @"";
    state.text = @"";
    phoneNO.text = @"";
    injuryStatus.text = @"";
    emailAddress.text = @"";

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    status.text = @"Person saved";
}
```

Is there any othere way to map my BO with coredata other than this?

Comment: What do you mean to map a BO in Core Data? Do you have already a data model? As I see from your code, you are using a Person entity. So, what's your goal? Thanks.

Comment: My goal is to map my BO to coredata so it will populate my personInfoBO automatically by mapping model object, but cannot able to create mapping model.Here is link i am following http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html

Comment: With *mapping model* do you mean the Data Model?

Comment: just tell me how to apply sql queries like update ,delete,find second max,joins,view etc in core data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tahir first you must create Coredata db which you already create. Next select table in Entity panel in coredata model.Right click model in project hirarchy tree. Select new file , select coredata and NSManagedObjectSubclass and than save it. It create model class for coredata table which you can use in your methods.[image]

This image show selection of db and table to right click and select NSManagedObjectSubClass

[image]

This image show selection of first coredata than NSManagedObjectSubClass and after this when you click next it show you panal to give name and save this in your project.
I hope this will help you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> just tell me how to apply sql queries like update ,delete,find second
>   max,joins,view etc in core data

Since Core Data covers a lot of stuff, I can give some hints.

First of all, dealing with Core Data means dealing with managed objects that "lives" in a sort of scratchpad that is called `NSManagedObject`. Think to it as a sort of container graph that contains the objects that are retrieved from the file (e.g. sql file) based on the Data Model you have created. Until you don't save a context, changes resides in memory and are not stored physically.

```
[moc save:&error];
```

With the `NSManagedObject` you can create, update, query or delete objects. And do other stuff, of course.

If you need to insert a new managed object (that is declared in your Data Model), you can use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`.

If you need to perform queries, you need to have a look to `NSFetchRequest` class. Setting up a `NSFetchRequest` is equivalent to a SELECT statetement in SQL language.

Here a simple example:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

// error handling code
```

The array `results` contains all the managed objects (the people) contained within the sqlite file. If you want to grab a specific object (or more objects) you need to use a predicate with that request. For example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName == %@", @"John"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

In this case `results` contains the objects (the people) where attribute is equal to `John`. Setting a predicate is equal to put the WHERE clause in a SQL statement.

If you want to set up joins, views, etc you need to perform correct `NSPredicates` among entities (based on relationships and attributes) and let Core Data do perform the row stuff for you.

If you need to delete an object, you need to do:

```
[moc deleteObject:managedObjectToDelete];
```

If you need to update a managed object, you have to create a fetch request and retrieve the object(s) you are looking for (e.g. you could provide to each object a specific id and set up a predicate with the id you want). If the fetch request retrieve some objects, then you can update them.

These are simple tips to guide you in using Core Data. I suggest you to read the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). There you can find a lot of stuff. If you want you can start with a good tutorial on using Core Data take a look to [www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started).

If you want something else let me know.

Hope it helps.