# Updating preloaded data alongside user-data in a Core Data app

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, preload

Simple problem, but for me, tough execution. I'm working solely on an app that is in alpha, but my testers need to have the most up-to-date database. I have a Core Data model with two entities: Clothing and ClothingRecord.

**Clothing** is a "static" model that has preloaded data (things like Hat, Shirt, Pants, etc) that will only change whenever I update the model.

**ClothingRecord** is user populated entity that has relationships with entity **Clothing**.

[image]

What I've just run into is that I want to change the data in **Clothing**. Not only change properties of Clothing (like change name from "Hat" to "Cap"), but I want to add and remove items as well.

I'm fairly new to Core Data so I used Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on how to preload data:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data

This worked great for the first time. I have a database up and running. Now, however, that I've changed it, I'm not sure how to properly update the **Clothing** entity. Do I traverse all objects and compare? Do I just add new things? I can't go and delete objects because of existing relationships, right?

Are there guides or tutorials on how to update a Core Data driven app with preloaded data? I would imagine that this is happens all of the time, but I can't find any solid resources on it.

Comment: I added an edit. Maybe could be of interest for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I traverse all objects and compare? Do I just add new things? I
>   can't go and delete objects because of existing relationships, right?

It depends. I'll try to give you some suggestions.

*Do I traverse all objects and compare?*

To traverse and compare, first, I will insert an attribute that works as an identifier (e.g. [guid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)). Having an identifier could let you to compare objects that you retrieve with Core Data. For example if "Hat" has a guid with `1234` and "Cap" has the same guid, you could simply fetch through the identifier and update that object with the new name. This is can be achieved by setting up a `NSPredicate` ([how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571786/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data)).

*Do I just add new things?*

You can do it if you have no relationships with the second entity. On contrary you need to link the new object with the original relationships.

*I can't go and delete objects because of existing relationships*

The same as before, you need to ricreate those relationships and then delete the objects you are interested in.

I will try the first solution, if you have just started with CD. I also suggest an old answer that I wrote in a previous SO post about Core Data in general ([mapping-business-objects-with-core-data-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619613/mapping-business-objects-with-core-data-in-ios)).

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

About the last two options, you could perform a two steps operation.

First, create a request that let you to grab the pre-populated `Clothing` objects.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Clothing" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The array `results` contains the objects retrieved, now with a `for-loop` create new object and set right relationships.

```
for(Clothing* clothing in results) {

    Clothing* newClothing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Clothing" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    newClothing.name = @"Cap";
    newClothing.relationshipToWhatYouWant = clothing.relationshipToWhatYouWant;
}
```

Finally, if you want, remove the old objects.

P.S. Check the code because I've written by hand.