# Displaying data from a database - CoreData the way to go?

Tags: ios, database, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I've developed quite a few local apps, however this is the first time I'm introducing networking (more specifically posting to, and reading from a database). I am receiving back a JSON object from the database but I am currently using arrays and dictionaries. The objects do have relationships to each other, and I was wondering whether CoreData is the way to go. If so, do I just replicate part of the database I wish to be made viewable in the app and store it in my CoreData model? Are there any tutorials out there for this?

Also, just as a side note, I've also included Facebook integration with which I download the users list of friends. Would CoreData be good for storing this kind of information too? Or would I be better sticking with dictionaries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience (other could say different things) Core Data is the right choice but its adoption could depend on the time you could dedicate to it. At first could be very complicated but I think you could take advantage applying the knowledge in some other projects.

Out of there there are some tutorials or books on Core Data.

First I suggest to read about [core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started). In the site there are, I think, other tutorials. Then, you could try to read a post on core data I've written some time ago: [Mapping Business Objects with Core Data in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619613/mapping-business-objects-with-core-data-in-ios/10681386#10681386). Also Apple doc is your friend. So read the [Introduction to Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) to have the details that are going on.

> If so, do I just replicate part of the database I wish to be made
>   viewable in the app and store it in my CoreData model?

Yes, just a part. You can create a minimal model that includes the key parts you need to have in your device. What I want to highlight is that you don't need to take care of normalization concepts when you deal with Core Data. Yes you could, but in CD you deal with objects and it's important to make attention to memory consumption (the framework helps you) and performances.

> Would CoreData be good for storing this kind of information too? Or
>   would I be better sticking with dictionaries?

With CD you could take advantage of `NSFetchedResultsController`. A `NSFetchedResultsController` objects is optimized to work with tables and it used to display data also in batches. Through this component you can deal with a lot of elements (say friends in Facebook) without overload the memory. See [core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

If you want to know something else, let me know.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent, very concise. Thanks.