# Parsing JSON to Core Data

Tags: ios, json, parsing, rest, core-data

I'm trying to parse JSON from a drupal page to an iOS device. This is the JSON format:

```
[{"nid":"20","name":"job 234"},{"nid":"21","name":"job 3534"}]
```

These are two objects. How do I save them using coredata, and a custom entity? I guess I need matching names for the attributes? Any links or tips will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PonyLand,

Your question is quite general but I'll try to give you some hints. To achieve your goal you could follow a two steps process:

1. Parse JSON Data and retrieve objects
2. Save objects in Core Data

To parse your JSON data you could follow [working-with-json-in-ios-5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5). This tutorial applies to iOS 5. If iOS 5 isn't the only target you could take a look to [iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial) resources.

Once you have parsed JSON Data, you need to use Core Data to save them. You can find how to use Core Data in the following tutorial: [core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started). Furthermore, you can find a simple explanation (made by me) on Core data in [Mapping Business Objects with Core Data in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619613/mapping-business-objects-with-core-data-in-ios).
If you need to use table take a look at [core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

About your Core Data model, you could create a single entity called `Job` (for example) with two attributes:

- `nid` of type `NSString` (or `NSNumber`)
- `name` of type `NSString`

If you want to know something else, let me know.

You could also try to use [RestKit](http://restkit.org) (that supports Core Data), but I think it could be easier to follow the two steps process I wrote.

Finally, [Core Data programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is your friend.

Hope that helps.